# Firebase how to check if snapshot's children are of type Datasnapshot themselves

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I check if the child `LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP` has children that are other `Datasnapshot`s and not `k/v` pairs like in **eg. 1**?

I tried all of these but none worked:

```
Database.database().reference().child("LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.hasChildren() { return }

    guard snapshot.children.allObjects is [DataSnapshot] else { return }

    guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

    print("this print statement should only get reached if there are Datasnapshots underneath of it")

})
```

In the above code (from **eg. 1** below) the print statement gets reached because there are children but they are only dict values. I want it so that the it doesn't get reached specifically because there aren't any Datasnapshots underneath of it.

**eg. 1** Children that are dict values and no Datasnapshots

```
-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP
  |
  |---"key1":"value1"
  |---"key2":"value2"
  |---"key3":"value3"
```

The print statement should only get reached if there are Datasnapshots like in **eg. 2** below

**eg. 2** Children that are dict values and 2 Datasnapshots

```
-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP
  |
  |---"key1":"value1"
  |---"key2":"value2"
  |---"key3":"value3"
  |
  @-LlzB3_ppHHVmdipXs
  |     
  @-LlzD8p5-WOT-ZZhfc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using definitions that are slightly off, which makes it hard to implement.

Let's first set the correct definition of what data in the database becomes a `DataSnapshot` in the client:

Say you have this JSON in the database:

```
"-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP": {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

If you load this JSON from the database into the app, you get a single top-level snapshot with key `-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP`. This snapshot has three child snapshots, one for each key under it. The fact that the value of each of those keys is a primitive string value, doesn't matter: they're still each a `DataSnapshot`. So in the above JSON there are four snapshots, with keys `-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP`, `key1`, `key2`, and `key3`.

---

The difference is in the type of the value of the child `DataSnapshot`s. So if you want to know if he value of a certain `DataSnapshot` is itself a complex type again, you can do something like **for each child snapshot**:

```
snapshot?.value is Dictionary
```

Alternatively you can check **for each child snapshot** whether they have children:

```
snapshot?.hasChildren()
```

For `-LojqctqkDpthbF_TYvP` the above tests will both be true, while for the other keys they'll be false.

Comment: Ahhhh I didn’t know that a primitive would also be considered a Datasnapshot. **Thanks for the that!** It makes sense though because all keys are String types anyway. I’ll be at my computer in about an hour or so and try it out.

Comment: In my question I tried if !snapshot.hasChildren and it didn’t work.

Comment: Yeah, it's a method. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#haschildren

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I actually just added a child with a name underneath of it and checked for that name which was easier and more importantly clearer. As usual your help is much appreciated. Cheers!